# How do I prevent exclamations via a regex

Tags: java, regex

```
public static final String REGEX_ADDRESS_ZIP = "^[0-9\\ -.]+$";
```

The above regex for validating zip code seems to allow exclamation (!) even though I haven't allowed it here. Not sure what the mistake is? Do I need to change the regex pattern

Comment: It doesn't seem to me, this regex accept only numbers dash and dot. Could you give an example ?

Comment: You don't have to escape spaces. `[0-9 .-]` works fine.

Comment: Ahh yes, we've all done this one :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hyphen `-` is a metacharacter inside [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) unless it is the first or last character. Change it to:

```
^[0-9\\ .-]+$
```

`[0-9\\ -.]` means any character from `0` to `9` (all digits), the backslash `\`, and any character from space (ASCII 32) to period (ASCII 46) [which translates to](http://ascii-table.com/):

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-.
```